# Download File from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, download, azure-blob-storage

I have an application that allows users to upload photos, which are stored in Azure Blob Storage. The user also has the ability to view these photos. To view them, we want the application to download the image to the default download location. At the moment, the upload works perfect. But the download function that I found for Azure API doesn't seem to be doing anything. Also, I can't really specify a download location because this functionality needs to work on desktop/laptops as well as on mobile devices which have different default directories.

This seems like it should be simple but I cannot find anything to help me.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("photos");
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(photo.BlobUrl);
//copy blob from cloud to local gallery
blob.DownloadToFile(photo.ImageName);
```

The `blob.DownloadToFile(photo.ImageName);` causes a server request but nothing happens, aka no file is downloaded.

Comment: no reference for 'photo' object ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any reason you cannot have the client download the file directly from blob storage and use the built-in browser capability to save it?  If the files are private, it is pretty easy to generate a SAS signature.  This will offload the download from coming through your server and remove that overhead.

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: @Demodave , make the container public (in azure portal), and then the client can just reference the azure storage uri of the blob and download over http/s.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
blob.DownloadToFile(photo.ImageName);
```

You need to tell it where to save the file and the name you want it to be:

```
blob.DownloadToFile("C:\mycutepuppy.jpg");
```

You could use System.Environment.SpecialFolder enum to figure out the folder based on the current system then append what you want the image name to be;

Here is a more complete example:

```
var imgPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), + photo.ImageName);

blob.DownloadToFile(imgPath);
```

This would save the image to the correct path where the user's desktop directory is.  Here is the documentation on that enum for special folders.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Comment: What if I want to let the user select the path?

Comment: Then you would prepend their path in front of your image name like: string userPath = "Whatever they picked";  So it would be var imgPath = userPath + photo.ImgName;  You might want to check that the directory exists as well before you try to save there.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder what do you expect from this code, but especially in the case of different platform this would not work. I suggest that you use the [DownloadToStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadtostream.aspx) method instead. Then you can decide what to do with the stream. For example ask the user where does he want to save the file.

Comment: Corrected - especially for @Eric!

Comment: Well, you can also use DownloadToStreamAsync if you fast forward to 2018... The answer was posted in 2012, @MdAslam